# Cypress: How to test zooming in/out with MMB

Tags: cypress

I am to write a test that checks the zooming in/out functionality by scrolling the middle mouse button, but I cannot find any way to test this?

The element that is changing while manually scroll the MMB is

```html
<div class="react-transform-component" style="transform: translate3d(-180.78px, -56.96px, 0px) scale(1.213);">
```

The most recent thing I tried and that did not work was

```js
cy.getCanvas().click().trigger("scroll", 0, 50);
```

(canvas element is inside of the `react-transform-component`)

EDIT: Manually editing the style attribute kind of works but it doesn't really test scrolling (scrolling with MMB changes zoom percentage text which doesn't get changed with this)

```js
cy.get(".react-transform-component")
    .should(
        "have.attr",
        "style",
        "transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);"
    )
    .wait(5000)
    .invoke(
        "attr",
        "style",
        "transform: translate3d(-151.84px, -32.64px, 0px) scale(1.16);"
    )
    .should(
        "have.attr",
        "style",
        "transform: translate3d(-151.84px, -32.64px, 0px) scale(1.16);"
    );
```

Comment: Is it really not possible? :/